# Contact form with Bootstrap + Php not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner and I am trying to use this tutoriel http://untame.net/2013/05/how-to-build-a-modal-contact-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-with-php-ajax for creating my contact form. Email not sending ! Do you have an idea, why ? Thanks for your help !

After clicking on Send I have this on adresse web : http://viktorius.fr/?question=&email=&save=contact

Here the HTML code :

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/glyphicons_012_heart.png"></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="What is your question ?">                                        
                                    </div>

                                    <h5 id="Email" align="left" color="#000"<span style="color:black">For the answer, let us your email :</h5>


                                 <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/glyphicons_290_skull.png"></span></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Email">                                        
                                    </div>



       <!-- Form itself -->


        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button><br />
```

Here the PHP code :

```
<?php
ini_set(“SMTP”,”smtp.viktorius.fr”);
ini_set(“smtp_port”,”25″);
$myemail = 'postmaster@viktorius.fr';
if (isset($_POST['question'])) {
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Question:</strong> ".$question."<br>";
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>";
```

Comment: Those two backticks before `if(isset($_POST['name']))` isn't part of your code, *right*? If they are, remove them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, not on my code. I don't know why this backticks are here !

Comment: I removed the backticks from your question/code.

Comment: Do you see #thanks message after you submit the form ?

Comment: You're including multiple versions of jQuery and Bootstrap.js !

Comment: @hutchbat No #thanks message. Nothing happens. 
So I have to put 1 Jquery and 1 Boostrap version, right ?

Comment: [enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) and add debug information because guessing isn't a developers way to debug. You are also open to header injection.

Comment: @user3723137 Sure ! jQuery & Bootstrap js should only included once. and you need to correct the name of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))

<input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="What is your question ?">
```

Check the name of your inputs, php cant read your post data.

Comment: I've changed the inputs by question and email.

Here the HTML code :

`<input id="question" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="What is your question ?">`

`<input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" "placeholder="For the answer, let us your email adress here :">`

Comment: Here the PHP code :

`<?php
$myemail = 'postmaster@viktorius.fr';
if (isset($_POST['question'])) {
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Question:</strong> ".$question."<br>";
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>";`

But it doesn't work I don't understand.

Comment: @user3723137 If you have changed something on your code, If I may suggest to edit also your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single form here...

the ajax expects to serialize

```
<form class="contact">...

$('form.contact').serialize(),
```

And you don't have a form 
You should put all your inputs and button inside a form tag with class contact like this:

```
<form action="" class="contact">    
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/glyphicons_012_heart.png"></span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="What is your question ?">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px;" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="img/glyphicons_290_skull.png"></span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" color="#000000"placeholder="For the answer, let us your email adress here :">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !

I am trying your solution. I have this adress web after click on submit : 

`http://viktorius.fr/?question=Where+is+the+Eiffel+Tower+%3F&email=test%40test.com&save=contact`

Do you have an idea, why ?